# Not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:ID'

Tags: fusionauth

Trouble getting FusionAuth as IDP to pass samltest.id.

FusionAuth installed on test.example.com upstream of NGINX with SSL, all on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Create application in FusionAuth**

Name: SamlTest

Id: 1214aabe-5697-44bd-a271-511d43b63913

**In SAML tab set [1]**

Issuer: https://samltest.id/saml/sp

ACS: https://samltest.id/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

**View application, under SAML v2 Integration details**

Metadata URL: https://test.example.com/samlv2/metadata/63326230-3433-3661-3939-626632386436

**Provide Metadata URL to samltest.id [2] and get following errors**

moment.metadata:1: element EntityDescriptor: Schemas validity error : Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}EntityDescriptor', attribute 'ID': '64643134-3530-3365-6433-393236336261' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:ID'.

moment.metadata:1: element IDPSSODescriptor: Schemas validity error : Element '{urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata}IDPSSODescriptor': The attribute 'protocolSupportEnumeration' is required but missing.
moment.metadata fails to validate

Is it possible that the ID needs to start with something other than a number [3]?

**EDIT1 - start**

Fairly certain that the issue identified in [3] is what's triggering the first error. Manually modified XML file, prepended ID with an _ (underscore) and submitted it to a local Shibboleth SP install and that got rid of the 'xs:ID' error.

I don't think we can resolve the 'protocolSupportEnumeration' missing error.

**EDIT 1 - end***

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[1] https://samltest.id/download/#SAMLtest_Metadata

[2] https://samltest.id/upload.php

[3] https://docs.secureauth.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6226279

Comment: Is this the same issue described here? https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/235

Comment: Yes. Marked as answered and Github reference given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed by developer with patch to fusionauth-samlv2-X.Y.Z.jar.

See discussion here: [Github](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/235)